# Why this lua function is modifying tables it shouldn't?

Tags: lua

I have this function in my code to load and setup sizes for sprites.

```
function aux.Sprite:setTexture(renderer,imgPath)
     ... -- Not important for this question
     img = loadImage(renderer,imgPath)
     self.texture = img.texture
     self.rect.w = img.w
     self.rect.h = img.h
end
```

(loadImage here is the function implemented in C, and is returning the correct values)

Using it should be easy enough

```
bg = aux.Sprite:new()
bg:setTexture(R, "testfiles/bg.png")
ship = aux.Sprite:new()
ship:setTexture(R, "testfiles/testship.png")
```

The problem is that after the second call for **setTexture** the values for the FIRST sprite is changed!

for example

```
bg = aux.Sprite:new()
bg:setTexture(R, "testfiles/bg.png")
print(bg.rect.w)
ship = aux.Sprite:new()
ship:setTexture(R, "testfiles/testship.png")
print(bg.rect.w)
```

should return
1920 1920
because I'm printing the width for bg twice

but I'm getting
1920
300
That is, the second setTexture changes the value for "bg" and not only for "ship".

My guess is that `self.rect.w = img.w`  is setting a "pointer", or whatever is called in lua, to img.w and when I use the function later this pointer is updated in all references?

What I'm doing wrong here? Is this the correct lua behavior?

PS: The definition of the Sprite:new function as asked

```
function aux.Sprite:new(o)
     o = o or {}
     setmetatable(o, self)
     self.__index = self
     return o
end
```

Comment: What is the definition of `aux.Sprite:new`?

Comment: @MichałPolitowski added the definition to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the provided code that actually creates the `rect` (or `aux.Sprite` for that matter). I guess this means that is done via something like

`aux.Sprite = { rect = {} }`

This is a problem because it means all your sprites share the same `rect`.

`aux.Sprite:new()` returns a new *empty* table that has the metatable and its `__index` set to `Sprite`. Thus when in `setTexture` `self.rect` is searched in this empty table the one from `Sprite` is returned via `__index`.

You need to make sure every sprite has its own unique `rect`.
I don't really know what is the typical Lua object pattern here, but you can eg. have `self.rect = { w = img.w, h = img.h }` in `setTexture` or maybe `o.rect = {}` in `new` - something that actually sets `rect` to a new table for this particular sprite.

Comment: thank you, setting the rect in new worked.